# Links to my own website not allowed?

Tags: support, hyperlinks, markdown

I was just testing my website's would-be editor - wmd.

I had accidentally encoded my input which produced<sup>++</sup>

```
**strong text** *emphasized text* [link text][1]&#13;&#10;&#13;&#10;    enter code here&#13;&#10;    &#13;&#10;    &#13;&#10;`&lt;hr/&gt;`&#13;&#10;&#13;&#10;![alt text][2]&#13;&#10;&#13;&#10;    &#13;&#10;&#13;&#10; 1. List item&#13;&#10; 2. Bye&#13;&#10; &#13;&#10;&#13;&#10;Cool&#13;&#10;&#13;&#10; - List item&#13;&#10; - Cool&#13;&#10; &#13;&#10;&#13;&#10;--------&#13;&#10; &#13;&#10;&#13;&#10;  [1]: http://nettpals.in&#13;&#10;  [2]: http://i.imgur.com/1cZl4.jpg
```

which made my wmd-editor go crazy. I thought of seeing how SO's editor would handle this, but what I found made me ask this question.

A warning was given:

> Links to http://nettpals.in are not allowed

WTH? My website is new and does no illegal activities or any such things. I want to know why this is happening?

<sup>++</sup> <sub>I've formatted the text as code since Meta gave me the same warning otherwise.</sub>

Comment: I suspect the error message could do with minor rewording. It implies that a specific domain has been blacklisted, but given Martijn's answer, this is not the case with your website.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are using HTML entities in the URL; Stack Exchange assumes you are deliberately trying to bypass the URL filter when you do that and refuses to allow the URL. The fact that these entities encode line separators doesn't matter.

Linking to your site without HTML entities [works *just fine*](http://nettpals.in/).

Comment: cool! But may I know how you know all these internal details? Employee of SE?

Comment: @AmitJoki: no, knowledge about other things SE does which are already public knowledge plus my own experience as a web developer gave me a hypothesis, and a quick test confirmed it.

Comment: @AmitJoki: in other words: I used Science!

Comment: you're a clever ninja `:)`

Comment: Go science! :D)

Comment: In other words, he is a programmer.

Comment: Science ninja programmer!

Comment: In other words he is Martijn, son of Jon Skeet.

Comment: @AmitJoki - this is the type of information you get to know by hanging around on meta a lot. [se] developers often explain certain functionality when addressing bugs or feature-requests.